# Monodevelop keeps crashing when I add an image into a gtk window using the pixbuf option in the properties window

Tags: c#, crash, gtk, monodevelop, gtk#

I'm making a simple app for a school homework project and I'm trying to add an image but every time I do the IDE crashes and if i somehow manage to compile it, when I go on to that window the whole program crashes. It doesn't give me an error and when i open it in the terminal nothing is output.

I've tried using the included icons, I've tried to import it into the project directory and i've tried to access it as a link to a file but all to no avail.

This is the section of the build that handles the image files but I don't really know what I'm doing as this is the first gtk application I've made. I can provide further code snippets as necessary. I can't provide any examples of code when the image is loaded into the program because it crashes instantly.

```cs
// Container child hbox6.Gtk.Box+BoxChild
            this.image1 = new global::Gtk.Image();
            this.image1.Name = "image1";
            this.hbox6.Add(this.image1);
            global::Gtk.Box.BoxChild w6 = ((global::Gtk.Box.BoxChild)(this.hbox6[this.image1]));
            w6.Position = 0;
            w6.Expand = false;
            w6.Fill = false;
            // Container child hbox6.Gtk.Box+BoxChild
            this.image2 = new global::Gtk.Image();
            this.image2.Name = "image2";
            this.hbox6.Add(this.image2);
            global::Gtk.Box.BoxChild w7 = ((global::Gtk.Box.BoxChild)(this.hbox6[this.image2]));
            w7.Position = 1;
            w7.Expand = false;
            w7.Fill = false;
            this.hbox3.Add(this.hbox6);
            global::Gtk.Box.BoxChild w8 = ((global::Gtk.Box.BoxChild)(this.hbox3[this.hbox6]));
            w8.Position = 0;
            w8.Expand = false;
            w8.Fill = false;
            // Container child hbox3.Gtk.Box+BoxChild
            this.hbox4 = new global::Gtk.HBox();
            this.hbox4.Name = "hbox4";
            this.hbox4.Spacing = 6;
            // Container child hbox4.Gtk.Box+BoxChild
            this.image3 = new global::Gtk.Image();
            this.image3.Name = "image3";
            this.hbox4.Add(this.image3);
            global::Gtk.Box.BoxChild w9 = ((global::Gtk.Box.BoxChild)(this.hbox4[this.image3]));
            w9.Position = 0;
            w9.Expand = false;
            w9.Fill = false;
            // Container child hbox4.Gtk.Box+BoxChild
            this.image4 = new global::Gtk.Image();
            this.image4.Name = "image4";
            this.hbox4.Add(this.image4);
            global::Gtk.Box.BoxChild w10 = ((global::Gtk.Box.BoxChild)(this.hbox4[this.image4]));
            w10.Position = 1;
            w10.Expand = false;
            w10.Fill = false;
```

There are no error messages because the whole thing just either crashes outright or stops responding, so I can't provide anything like that. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Are you using the designer in MonoDevelop to create your GTK# Form?

Comment: I am using the designer, yes. When I go into the properties tab and set it that way it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need to use the designer for such a simple task. Moreover, the designer always ties you to a given IDE (MonoDevelop, in this case). Graphic toolkits are far more intuitive than before, and many times it is trivial to understand how to work with them.

This is the whole code for a project which just shows an image in a window.

```
class MainWindow: Gtk.Window {
    public MainWindow()
        :base(Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
    {
        this.Build();


        this.DeleteEvent += (o, args) => Gtk.Application.Quit();
    }

    void Build()
    {
        var imgContainer = this.BuildEmbeddedImage();

        this.Add( imgContainer );
    }

    Gtk.Image BuildExternalImage()
    {
        return new Gtk.Image( "res/prowl.jpg" );
    }

    Gtk.Image BuildEmbeddedImage()
    {
        var pixbufImage = new Gdk.Pixbuf(
            System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(),
            "CSShowImage.res.prowl.jpg");

        return new Gtk.Image( pixbufImage );
    }
}

class Ppal
{
    [System.STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Gtk.Application.Init();
        new MainWindow().ShowAll();
        Gtk.Application.Run();
    }
}
```

For that code to work, you have to do the following:

1. Download an image. I downloaded an image about the autobot PROWL, and called it prowl.jpg, but you can choose whatever you want, of course.
2. Create a directory in your project through MonoDevelop (right-click the project and select "new folder").
3. Copy your image to that folder: right-click the newly created folder (I called that folder "res"), and choose "add files", copying the image to that folder when MonoDevelop asks what to do.
4. Right-click the image and select "quick properties >> copy to output directory". This will make the `BuildExternalImage()` method work. You can skip this step if don't plan to use an external image. Take into account that, this way, you'll have to distribute the image (in a directory called "res") with the executable.
5. Right-click the image and select "build action >> EmbbeddedResource". This will make the method `BuildEmbeddedImage()` work. The image will be inside your executable, no need to worry about anything else. The only caveat is that in `BuildEmbeddedImage`, instead of the line reading "CSShowImage.res.prowl.jpg" you have to create your own string with the name of the project, the name of the directory with the image, and the name of the image. For example, if your project is called "HomeWork", you created the folder as "res", and your image is "myfamily.jpg", then the resulting string would be "HomeWork.res.myfamily.jpg"

If you insist on using the designer, then:

1. Create a new project in MonoDevelop of the Gtk# 2.0 section
2. Go to MainWindow.cs and go into the designer.
3. Drop an Image widget from the toolbox inside your window being designed. MonoDevelop will complain about you using a widget instead a Container (such as VBox), and then a widget inside it. Go ahead with whichever option.
4. Select the image widget and go to properties, unfold "image properties". In pixbuf, click the "..." button. Go the resources folder. Click "add" and choose your image. MonoDevelop will do the heavy work for you, and the image will appear in the designer right now.
5. Click "run".

To be honest, MonoDevelop crashed on the first execution, but appeared to be stable when opening the project one again.

Hope this helps.